# Parsing a comment made by "github-actions" bot into JSON

Tags: json, github, github-actions

On every pull request that has a specific label our github-actions bot makes an automatic comment that includes a template which needs to be edited by the PR approver, before it can be merged.

The template the bot comments is as follows:

```
        **Hello, @${{ github.actor }}!**
        **This component is critical!**
        **Edit and input the following BEFORE approving the PR!**
        ___
        * Description: XXXXXXXXXX
        * Justification: XXXXXXXXXX

        The last change was authored by:
        @${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}
```

The Description and Justification fields are replaced with actual values manually by the PR approver (it is not possible to know these in advance). Their values need to be saved as: **change_description** and **justification** to be stored in a .json file like so:

```
{"change_date": "<Date when PR Merged>", "change_id": "<Pull Request Link>", "change_description": "<from PR Comment>", "component": "<from terragrunt.hcl file>", "justification": "<from PR Comment>", "team": "<from terragrunt.hcl file>"}
```

I've gotten as far as saving the comment body as an environment variable in a new Github action, where I want to parse the comment and save it into a .json file:

```
  env:
    BODY: ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
```

All of the logic so far as been simple enough, but now I cannot find a way to pull the values of the Description and Justification from the comment body after they are edited manually. Is this not possible via Github Actions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible in GitHub Actions.
You have to use regular expressions and bash to parse desired values.

Here is example of regexp to get one of your variables:

`\*\*Hello, (.*)\*\*`

https://regex101.com/r/Wfww5Y/1

End then in bash you can do:

```
[[ $body =~ $regex ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```